# Bijective function transforming tuples into integer

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

I have a list of tuples of integers where each number can be `{0, 1, 2}`. For example the tuples (1, 0, 2, 1, 0) and (2, 1, 0, 0, 0). Is there a way to identify these tuples with a unique integer representation and to be able to find them back with a bijective function ? 
I tried to apply the [weighted sum model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_sum_model) but I did not manage to get the result wanted.

Thank in advance

Comment: does (x,y,.....z) -> xy....z in base 10 expansion work? Are you using ordered tuples?

Comment: Each ordered tuple is the unique expression of an integer in base 3 (or base 10, as @user27182 says), so the map in injective. It's not bijective unless your list has all the tuples (of some fixed length).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just transform the sequence into a base-$3$ number: $a_03^0+a_13^1+\cdots $

Answer (score 1):

The function that maps $\{e_{1}, e_{2}, \dots \}$ to $p_{1}^{e_{1}} \cdot p_{2}^{e_{2}} \cdots$, where $p_{i}$ is the $i$th prime number is bijective.